# Visual Studio 2015 Extraction Rule Issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, performance-testing, load-testing

I am attempting to create a performance test to capture login and order status from my site.  The recording is simply a login page and click a radio button to populate some data.  So on initial record with one user, the test works fine.  However, when I add a data source with multiple users, I get a postback error on the last page which populates my results.  My details just say

> 500 internal server error

I have a parameter called `UnitMemberList` which contains the results from the radio button.  The response looks like this:

```
<select name="Ti2$P$content$content$unitMemberList" id="Ti2_P_content_content_unitMemberList" style="width:350px;">
                                    <option value="23505183">100690 - Paula</option>
                                    <option value="10008483633">L76753 - VICTORIA</option>
                                    <option value="10001974885">F55115 - Esther</option>
                                    <option value="10008313924">K86743 - LUCIA</option>
                                    <option value="10007718454">I68327 - GUADALUPE</option>
                                    <option value="10009940400">U99948 - MARIA SONIA</option>
                                    <option value="10008115322">K17051 - MARICELA</option>
                                    <option value="10009928413">U95563 - DANIELA</option>
                                    <option value="10010367156">W65214 - MACRINA</option>
                                    <option value="10000893346">A78549 - Erendira</option>
                                    <option value="10007569390">I13064 - MARIANA</option>
                                    <option value="10001326244">C70591 - Lidia</option>

                                </select>
```

Is there a way to just capture the contents of the option values?  Everything from option to /option?  I can't extract by `option value=` as there are several of these throughout the response.  Also, on the first run, the captured content is just the first number `23505183` and that is stored for the parameter `UnitMemberList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had more than one match from my response.  I changed my regex to use a digit match instead of character.